# onClick ID with Class

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

I have an object with the class `active` and another class `achievementsIndicator`. 
The `active` part of the class is something that i add and remove, so it is not static. What i want is a function to fire when you click the object and the `active` class is on. Here is some to clarify a bit better what i want to achive, this is how i imagined it:

```
$(.achievementsIndicator.active).onclick(function(){ ...function goes here...  })
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Event delegation.

Add event to parent of the div's:

```
$([parent selector]).on("click",".achievementsIndicator.active",function(){ ...function goes here...  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
$(document).ready(function(){
$('element.achievementsIndicator.active').on('click', function(){

```
 ...function goes here...
```

});
});

Include the element on your selector with achievementsIndicator and active class.